# NullPointerException thrown for no reason

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

A `NullPointerException` is being thrown on line 33 of this code:

```
|31|  @Override
|32|  public float[] getVertices() {
|33|    return new float[] {
|34|      center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 0, 1,
|35|      center.x + radius, center.y + radius, 1, 0,
|36|      center.x - radius, center.y + radius, 0, 0,
|37|      center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 0, 1,
|38|      center.x + radius, center.y - radius, 1, 1,
|39|      center.x + radius, center.y + radius, 1, 0
|40|    };
|41|  }
```

I know there are lots of reasons for `NullPointerExceptions` to be thrown, but I just don't see anything on that line causing an exception.

`center.x`, `center.y`, and `radius` are all defined previously in the code, so they are not null.  I did a `Log.v(TAG, "center.x: " + center.x + ", center.y: " + center.y + ", radius: " + radius)`, just to check if they were defined, and this was the result: `center.x: 0, center.y: 0, radius, 1`

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.vcapra1.breakoutgame.objects.Ball.getVertices(Ball.java:33)
        at com.vcapra1.breakoutgame.objects.TextureObject.<init>(TextureObject.java:17)
        at com.vcapra1.breakoutgame.objects.Ball.<init>(Ball.java:16)
        at com.vcapra1.breakoutgame.BreakoutRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(BreakoutRenderer.java:66)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

Comment: maybe center is null?

Comment: Please construct a minimal test-case.

Comment: where/when did you log? - try logging just before creating the `float[]`.

Comment: @игор - it was just before line 33 (which was line 34 when the log was in there)

Comment: is the `center` changed from the outside? It may be changed to `null` between the log and `float[]` creation?

Comment: it's for sure one of center or redius is null could u post full code and the full stack trace specially if u get caused by

Comment: Why do so many people think logging is the way to go?  Logging is for, er, logging.  The debugger is for debugging.  With the debugger, you would find this in 10 seconds.  Why don't you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `center` or `radius` is `null`. Do you use primitives or 'big' types? If using classes, autoboxing may give you NPE as well.

Check *when* any of those variables is set, maybe it can be set after the logging, by some other event/thread that happens in the same time. Try syncing these two actions: resetting the `center`/`radius` and making an array.

Comment: center is an object, radius is primitive float

Comment: Can you please explain how `center` may change?

Comment: It seems, as you said, that center is being changed to null.  However, center is defined as a member variable at the top of the class, and is accessed inside this function.  If I redefine this at the top of the function, it works.  The variable is NEVER accessed, so what could be changing this??

Comment: sorry, not sure, would have to see that :) try for example to use setter/getter and get center instance before float[] is created; then debug when center is modified... just saying the first things that i would do ;)

Comment: What do you mean "never accessed"?  If it's never accessed, how do you initialise it?  Show the initialisation, not the declaration.